# Tracking open windows and their titles

Tags: .net, winapi, windows-7, windows

I'm writing a small application for Windows 7 that will track focused programs and their titles. I've never worked with the required API.

Example: The app should run as a process and log everything to a db. If I open Firefox and surf to stackoverflow I would in the db have a row:

> "App: Mozilla firefox | Title: Question - Stack Overflow - Mozilla Firefox | Time: 18:07:40"

If I then continue and open Steam I would have a row:

> "App: Steam Client | Title: Store | Time: 18:08:40"

I just don't know where to begin. I've developed a bunch of stand alone apps with windows forms but I've never interacted with windows like this before. I've also done a share of ASP.NET development so I'm not a complete newbie. Since I'd like to install this as a process a UI isn't really necessary.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetWindowsHookEx` with `WH_CBT` will give you the info you need. You can use `WM_GETTEXT` to get window titles.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644959(VS.85).aspx#wh_cbthook